# Simple Sibling() jquery issue. Not appending class to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to append a class to my div which are children of a section and i've ran into some trouble.

Here is the basic code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Assignment 7 Starter File</title>

 <style>
  body {
        font-family:arial; font-size: 100%;
       }

  #outer {
          width: 800px;
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
          border: 1px solid #000;
          padding: 10px;
         }

  h2 {
      font-size: 16pt;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
     }

  h1 {
      font-size: 1.5em;
      text-align: center;
     }

  div {
       margin-bottom: 25px;
      }

  p {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 10px;
     }

 .bottomBorder {
                border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
               }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("a").attr("target" , "_blank"); // makes tabs open in new tab

      $("section #faq").siblings("div").addClass("bottomBorder"); //adds the class to the bottom of each div. Adds dots.

       $("<aside><h2> Links used:</h2></aside>").insertAfter("section #faq");

       $("a").clone().appendTo("aside").append("<br />");



  });

 </script>
</head>

  <body>
  <header>
      <h1>FAQ</h1>
  </header> 

   <section id="outer">

     <section id="faq">

    <div>
    <h2> What is jQuery?</h2>
     <p>jQuery is a JavaScript library intended to make writing JavaScript easier and fun. For more information visit <a href="http://www.jquery.com">jQuery.com</a>.
     </p>
   </div> 

    <div>
    <h2>How did jQuery Begin?</h2>
     <p>
     jQuery was developed in 2006 by John Resig, who is still the lead developer. For more information visit <a href="http://ejohn.org">ejohn.org</a>
     </p>
   </div> 

    <div>
    <h2>What is the jQuery UI?</h2>
     <p>
    jQuery UI provides abstractions for low-level interaction and animation. 
      Visit <a href="http://www.jqueryui.com">jQueryui.com</a>
     </p>
   </div>

     <div>
    <h2>What is Minification?</h2>
     <p class="content">
     Minification is  the process of removing all unnecessary characters from source code.
     </p>
   </div>

     </section>

     </section> <!-- end outer -->

  </body>
</html>
```

So basically i just want to insert that class into the div. But it won't work. It'll work just fine if the code is just a simple append without the sibling but it can't seem to get the sibling part down. any ideas?

Comment: What's `#faq` supposed to select?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, isn't the function `.siblings()`? Or is that a typo

Comment: Updated the code to include the whole page for more reference. Was too confusing originally. Yes that was a typo, thought it would fix it but not the case. Code is still wrong it seems.

Comment: but `#faq` does not have a `div` sibling? (only sections) do you mean to select the  `div` that are `.children()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You've got it pretty much right, but your jQuery selector is a little off. You're trying to put the class on that first `div` right? If so, this should work:

```
$("section#faq div").eq(0).addClass("bottomBorder");
```

Notice there's no space between `section` and `#faq` and then the `eq(n)` lets you pick which of the divs you want, 0 being the first.

**[EDIT updated answer from comments:]**

To add a class to all the divs matched by the selector, just add the class to that jQuery result array directly:

```
$("section#faq div").addClass("bottomBorder");
```

Notice that all the work is being done by the selector, which will match all divs inside a section that has the id "faq".

Comment: Thanks, i was actually trying to put it under all divs for an assignment. Usually you would probably only use siblings() for just picking one or two of them but in case i was to put it under all. append alone wasn't good enough.

Comment: oh, okay. if you want it on all the divs, just get rid of the `eq(0)`. So, `$("section#faq div").addClass("bottomBorder");` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using children function:

```
 $("section #faq").children("div").addClass("bottomBorder");
```

example [fiddlejs](https://fiddle.jshell.net/63mw2fbn/)